# Peewee union two tables without join

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, peewee

```
class Table1(Model):
    name = CharField()
class Table2(Model):
    name = CharField()
    table1_id = ForeignKeyField(Table1)
```

You need a query that combines these two tables:

```
select Table1.id, Table1.name, Table2.table1_id from Table1, Table1 where Table2.table1_id == Table1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.from_()`

E.g.

```
query = Table1.select(Table1, Table2.name).from_(Table1, Table2)
```

But in your example there is clearly a foreign-key, so I'm not sure why you would do this?

Comment: I just need to combine two related tables

Comment: My answer is what you want. Use the ".from_()" method.

Comment: Thank you, but where is the condition where Table2.table1_id == Table1.id

Comment: This code causes an error "KeyError: <class 'models.Table2'>", probably because the table "Table1" does not have a field "Table2.name". Help

Comment: i check so: len(query)